# How do I get my functions to configure the correct labels in tkinter in the following code?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I can do this when I individually create the labels so each function configures the label next to the button it's called from. When I try and create the labels with zip, the functions all configure the last label. I feel like I'm missing a step somewhere.  How can I do this so that each function configures the correct label without having to create each label separately ?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='light blue', height=1200, width=1200)

left_frame = Frame(root, width=250, height=500, bg='grey')
left_frame.place(x=10, y=10, relx=0.01, rely=0.01,)

def Create_Test():
    l.configure(text='Test result number 1')
def Create_test2():
    l.configure(text="Test result number 2")
def Create_test3():
    l.configure(text="Test result number 3")

text=['butt1', 'butt2', 'butt3','butt4']
Comm=[Create_Test, Create_test2, Create_test3]

for t,z in zip( text, Comm):
    butt=Button(left_frame, text=t, width=12, bg='red', fg='black', command=z, relief='ridge')
    butt.pack(side=TOP)

labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']
ys = [20, 47, 74]

for l,z in zip(labels,ys):
    l=Label(root, text="", width=25, bg='blue', fg='black',relief='ridge')
    l.place(x=125, y=z)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You used same variable `l` for the three labels, so after the for loop, `l` will reference to the last label.  You can use a list to store the three labels and access the corresponding label inside the three functions.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get things working after reading your comment. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try some lambda magic

Change

```
butt=Button(left_frame, text=t, width=12, bg='red', fg='black', command=z, relief='ridge')
```

to

```
butt=Button(left_frame, text=t, width=12, bg='red', fg='black', command=lambda z=z(): z, relief='ridge')
```

Note that you are also incorrectly trying to change the text of your labels. You re-use `l` to mean many different things in your code. The example I've provided below gives you a method to store each of the labels in a dictionary so you can change the contents of them later

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='light blue', height=1200, width=1200)

left_frame = Frame(root, width=250, height=500, bg='grey')
left_frame.grid()

def Create_Test():
    print(1)
    label_dict['Label1'].configure(text='Test result number 1')
def Create_test2():
    print(2)
    label_dict['Label2'].configure(text="Test result number 2")
def Create_test3():
    print(3)
    label_dict['Label3'].configure(text="Test result number 3")

text=['butt1', 'butt2', 'butt3']
labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3']
Comm=[Create_Test, Create_test2, Create_test3]

label_dict = {}

for idx,(button_text,label_text,fcn) in enumerate(zip(text,labels, Comm)):
    butt=Button(left_frame, text=button_text, width=12, bg='red', fg='black', command=lambda z=fcn:z(), relief='ridge')
    butt.grid(row=idx,column=0)
    currentLabel=Label(left_frame, text="", width=25, bg='blue', fg='black',relief='ridge')
    currentLabel.grid(row=idx,column=1)
    label_dict[label_text] = currentLabel


root.mainloop()
```

I've used .grid rather than your current mix of place and pack. Also I have a single loop to draw the buttons and labels since you can zip more than 2 iterables together.

Comment: Thanks Scotty. I'm very new to this and there's some interesting stuff in your answer that I haven't really explored before. Looking forward to trying it out .

Comment: `lamba` is scarier than it looks. If it was called `createFunction` it would be more obvious and less like black magic